# MobileFirst 6.3.0 Getting UnavailableShardsException

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server

After redeploy the application because a DB2 password update, the application was unable to be launched.
I found the following log:

```
[11/23/17 12:23:29:988 CST] 000000f1 DataReceiver  E   Error sending     bulk request: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in bulk execution:
[0]: index [worklight], type [app_activities], id [yRA1jtBzT9ScN0Hj-Fft0g], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][0] [2] shardIt,         [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@e38c893c]]
[3]: index [worklight], type [devices], id [c2062eef-e266-4209-83d2-13d043ae2a9d], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][2] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@34a9dfa3]]
[6]: index [worklight], type [devices], id [1ed55e4b-26e0-38ba-9f83-2b65d951722e], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][0] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@e38c893c]]
[8]: index [worklight], type [devices], id [1ed55e4b-26e0-38ba-9f83-2b65d951722e], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][0] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@e38c893c]]
[10]: index [worklight], type [app_activities], id [e4SxG701QwOwg7L5VztsTQ], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][0] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@e38c893c]]
[12]: index [worklight], type [devices], id [c2062eef-e266-4209-83d2-13d043ae2a9d], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][2] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@34a9dfa3]]
[13]: index [worklight], type [app_activities], id [wB2fqKAkT9-JAgfAqSPHZw], message [UnavailableShardsException[[worklight][0] [2] shardIt, [0] active : Timeout waiting for [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@e38c893c]]
    at com.ibm.elasticsearch.servlet.DataReceiver.processData(DataReceiver.java:132)
    at com.ibm.elasticsearch.servlet.DataReceiver.processDataLegacy(DataReceiver.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
```

I have not seen this error before

Comment: This problem is coming from the Operational Analytics part. Ideally updates to db2 shouldn't cause this problem, because Operational Analytics relies not on any DBs but only associated with the inbuilt elasticsearch module. Was it a multinode server or a single development server with both Analytics and MobileFirst on same server ?

Comment: It is a single development server with both Analytics and MFP on same server.

Comment: Can you check if you are able to just start only the analytics server (not the MFP) alone ? I think the AnalyticsData store might have got corrupted.